# crypto/bcrypt: hashedPassword is not the hash of the given password

Tags: hash, go, bcrypt

I encrypt user's password and save to db. Then to user login, compare hashed password and plain password, I'm getting `crypto/bcrypt: hashedPassword is not the hash of the given password` error. Whats wrong ?

```
func encryptPassword(password string) (string, error) {
    bytePass := []byte(password)
    hashedPassword, err := bcrypt.GenerateFromPassword(bytePass, bcrypt.DefaultCost)
    if err != nil {
        log.Printf("ERROR:EncryptPassword: %s", err.Error())
    }
    return string(hashedPassword), err
}

func (i *Impl) Register(user User) bool {
    hashedPass, err := encryptPassword(user.Password)
    if err != nil {
        return false
    }

    user.Password = hashedPass

    if err := i.DB.Create(&user).Error; err != nil {
        log.Printf("ERROR:Register: %s", err.Error())
        return false
    }
    return true
}

func (i *Impl) Login(email string, password string) (User, error) {
    var user User
    i.DB.Where("email = ?", email).First(&user)   

    err := bcrypt.CompareHashAndPassword([]byte(user.Password), []byte(password))
    if err != nil {
        log.Printf("ERROR:Login: %s", err.Error())
        return User{}, err
    }

    return user, err
}
```

Comment: Could you provide an example of the contents of `user.Password`

Comment: Have you compared the bytes from the DB to ensure it's getting updated properly, and not modified in any way?

Comment: for example, here is hashed password from db `$2a$10$rqHJJTHsxMbtX/5ZjG1mFuWyYbUDW1PLbfwQRN0uChwes38c/0m3e`, this generated from `123456`. Then I compare hashed password and plain password which is `123456` @Danilo @JimB

Comment: That hash doesn't work for me either.

Comment: `Register` takes a pointer to `User`, however when calling `i.DB.Create` you are using a pointer to a pointer. Is that on purpose?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/701012f1adc5c18b3076 This works for me. Maybe your initial hash is bad for some reason.

Comment: An often done mistake is the size of the database field, it should be `varchar(60)` or bigger to be future proof. The hash you provided looks ok, is it really extracted from the database? Another thing to check for are preceeding or trailing white spaces in the password.

Comment: size of db field is `varchar(255)` and there aren't whitespaces in the password. @martinstoeckli

Comment: Did you generate a new user since? The provided hash does not match the password `123456`.

Comment: yes, thats the problem. I registred new user with `123456` then user cannot login with this password.

Comment: @MelihMucuk the hash you provided `$2a$10$rqHJJTHsxMbtX/5ZjG1mFuWyYbUDW1PLbfwQRN0uChwes38c/0m3e` actually matches an empty password! When you are calling `Register` are you sure that `user.Password` contains the actual password before you feed it to `encryptPassword`?

Comment: Note for everyone reading this. I had a similar problem. Don't compare the hashed password from the DB with the HASH of the password. Compare it with the plain password. The interface of []byte and []byte was confusing me.

Answer (score 9):

My bet is that `user.Password` is empty in your `Register` function before you pass it to `encryptPassword` thus leading to hashes on empty passwords like the one you provided (`$2a$10$rqHJJTHsxMbtX/5ZjG1mFuWyYbUDW1PLbfwQRN0uChwes38c/0m3e`).

Comment: Yes, you can verify this easily with `fmt.Println(bcrypt.CompareHashAndPassword([]byte("$2a$10$rqHJJTHsxMbtX/5ZjG1mFuWyYbUDW1PLbfwQRN0uChwes38c/0m3e"), []byte{}))` which just prints `nil`. You should add a check to `encryptPassword` to make sure this doesn't happen.

Answer (score 3):

I cannot tell which is which, but in your compare function, ensure that you have the variables in the right place.

```
bcrypt.CompareHashAndPassword([]byte(user.Password), []byte(password))
           Must be the already hashed PW ^              ^ Plain Text Password to compare
```

Also ensure you're actually getting something to hash, you could be getting a blank password but not realizing it because the hash will still look full.

Comment: `user.Password` comes from db, so it's already hashed password.

Comment: @MelihMucuk are you sure it's bashing the right thing? Did you try to log what the value is before it gets hashed?

Answer (score 1):

My mistake was thinking that it compared two bcrypt hashedpasswords, rather than a hashedpassword and your unencrypted password converted to binary -- hope that helps someone out there!